# Why isn't VRAM upgradable?

Tags: gpu, vram

With the incessant arrival of new graphics cards, every one of them more powerful than before, I asked myself a simple question: why isn't VRAM as upgradable as system RAM?

More specifically, what are the physical or technical limitations that prevent adding VRAM sticks (if it was possible), for instance? 
I am interested in an answer that will tell me why it will *never* be the case or whether future technological improvements could make this possible. If so, what would be the type of technology that would make it possible?

If the question is too wide, I am happy to reformulate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest there are a number of reasons for this not being possible today and probably precluding this as an option into the future.

### Commercial / Political

This is an additional feature that just isn't required at the moment - it will take extra development time, make the product more expensive and may even make the product worse. If you were producing graphics cards, would you put more effort in to achieve these goals?

Additionally, the consumer will be required to "*do*" more to make use of the product (points outlined below), which will be less appealing to quite a number of the customer base. Customers opting for an "*all-in-one*" or "*not upgradable*" option will likely get a better product.

### Thermals

If you have a look, VRAM will often be thermally bonded to the large heatsink on the graphics card, if not then there will very probably be significant airflow over that area of the PCB, especially while working hard.

Video RAM is highgly performant and highly parallel, but that comes with increased thermal output that needs to be managed, [GDDR6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GDDR6_SDRAM) is a 384-bit wide interface and can achieve 768 GB/s.

In comparison [DDR4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR4_SDRAM) has a 64-bit bus and can achieve ~25 GB/s per channel, system memory often has heat spreaders, but in a standard desktop will rarely have active cooling or any significant heatsink.

### Timings & Logical Layout

The ability to simply purchase a stick of RAM and connect it to your motherboard is not simple to support... Aside from all the design considerations relating to the signals (matched lengths, termaination, etc...), each stick of RAM needs to be able to identify itself - how much memory it has, how that memory is laid out / presented, and a plethora of [timing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_timings) information.

This is additional complexity that graphics card manufacturers don't need to care about or even consider, because the memory is exactly what they specify.

The huge discrepancy between DDR4's 64-bit data bus, and GDDR6's 384-bit data bus also has serious impacts on how the memory is presented to the system. A single GDDR6 chip isn't going to have 384 pins, but multiple parts will be presented to the GPU's memory interface as at once. This means that "*not installing a module*" will result in holes on the address space that must be avoided... i.e: consumers will be *required* to fill *all* memory slots before the system will be operational, the alternative being significantly worse performance and a more narrow data bus.

For comparison, with DDR4 a single module is addressed at once... GDDR will address all modules and access data from all modules at once, which helps with performance.

### Practicality

If you add up the 384-bit data bus, a greater than 34-bit address bus (16 GB address space), all of the clock, control, power and ground interconnects, etc... you might end up with a memory module that has somewhere in the region of 500-600 pins... DDR4 modules have 288 pins.

As mentioned before, the alternative is a module with fewer pins, but a requirement that *all* modules are installed and matched.

If you then consider the signal integrity and various other aspects, then this problem becomes even worse.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see the limitations better now. So companies choosing to fit 4 or 8GB of VRAM is not simply a commercial move.

Comment: Not simply... but the BOM cost delta between the same card with 4GB and 8GB is going to be significantly smaller than the consumer would see... so that's is a commercial move / pricing strategy.

Comment: It took a better part of 2 decades to get the DDR standard.  While you could upgrade the system memory before that standard it really wasn't done due to cost.  Until the `Apple II` the ability to configure a computer was extremely limited.  It simply wasn't done except by the most extreme hobbyist.  If you don't believe the reason, graphics cards are not user configurable isn't due to wanting to sell additional hardware the next year, you would be mistaken.  That is precisely the reason you can not upgrade the GPUs nor the GDDR on a graphics card.

Comment: In comparison to building my own computer in the '80s.  I only recall getting a 4 MB graphics card in the late 1990s (in order to play the original Hitman).  As outlined by this answer, giving the user the ability to configure the specification of a graphic card comes at a cost, both with BOM and potential performance.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @Ramhound - is there anything in particular you'd like me to add / fix in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few reasons.

1. Some of the newest types of VRAM are not suited to mounting on an expansion card like a DIMM, because of the high bandwidth and much more critical timing (keeping signal paths to the GPU as short as possible). HBM/2/3/4 is an example of such a type of VRAM.
2. RAM on video cards is less standardized than on PC Motherboards.
3. Video cards are cheaper to manufacture without a DIMM or DIMM-like expansion slot.
4. Many users will never want to upgrade their VRAM.

Of these reasons, the first one is a technological hurdle that will likely be even more difficult to pass in the future (with video cards requiring even faster memory and even shorter signal paths). However, who knows what future technology will make upgradeable VRAM possible?

That said, I have certainly seen (and owned) older video cards that allowed VRAM to be upgraded by sticking in extra VRAM chips, like some S3 Trio64 cards (2D) and some early 3D cards (so we're talking some 20 years old).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was not clear enough in my question: I would not place the VRAM stick on the motherboard, but on the card directly, thus reducing the distance/solving the bandwidth issue.